# React Typescript with microbundle-crl doesnot create js file for files other than main file

Tags: reactjs, typescript

My folder structure is

```
src/lib/componentA.tsx
src/index.tsx
```

after running the build using `microbundle-crl` i get following

```
dist/lib/componentA.d.ts /* problem is that no js file is created at this path*/
dist/index.js
```

I am expecting `dist/lib/componentA.js` file too but it never gets created and all the logic is concatenated in one index.js which i donot want.
My tsconfig is as follows:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "dist",
    "module": "esnext",
    "lib": ["dom", "esnext"],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "jsx": "react",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist", "example"]
}
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Are you creating a React library? If yes why compiling to one js file an issue? If you have different types defined in different files and you want to expose them, you can have an index.ts which just does the necessary export, like [this](https://github.com/sidecus/authzyin.js/blob/master/src/index.ts).

Comment: @sidecus I want to access individual components 
import ComponentA  from 'mymodule/ComponentA' 
rather than 
import { ComponentA } from 'mymodule'.
i am importing them dynamically and this makes it much more readable.

Comment: fair enough. that is not controlled via tsconfig.json, instead it's by package.json though. can you try to update the source property to an array, like this:

  "source": ["src/componentA.ts","src/componentB.ts"],

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies. Will give it a try later, currently settled on using 2nd approach

Comment: @vcDevG What worked for you? I'm also having this problem.

Comment: @dcangulo i went with the import { ComponentA } from 'mymodule' for now

Comment: @vcDevG In my case I created a bash script that loops through all my files then executes for each file `microbundle-crl -i input_file -o dist/input_file.js`. Then executes the bash script on package.json's build script.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that the running jest will modify your `tsconfig.js` file.

I had to manually override `"allowJs": false` for my type definitions to work properly. Could be something similar.